# I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 and burned it onto a disk, it's an ISO file.. will it boot from disk?

Tags: 14.04, downloads, iso

I downloaded the .ISO file from the Ubuntu website, burned it to a [dvd] disc and before I wipe Windows (I don't have a spare  Windows disc) I want to know will it boot from the disk?

Comment: Use the Ubuntu dvd (yes it's bootable) to wipe windows.  Don't wipe it with any other tool.  Booting from the DVD will not wipe windows, you have to tell it do do that as part of the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is supposed to boot from the disk, and it will not touch your Windows installation until you tell it to.

Comment: Danke laddy! Bit of a newb haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% shure what your question means, but maybe this will help.
you are still able to just run ubuntu from the iso-disk without installing it if you startup from the disk.
No harm done then and you have your test if the stuff works.